# phonegap plugins barcodescanner disable menu button

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner, phonegap-build

I'm making an android app using phonegap. I'm using the barcodescanner plugin. I  have a slight problem though. When I click the menu button on my phone or in the emulator it   causes the app to crash. This only happens in the barcode scanning screen i.e. with the   camera actively looking for a barcode. I've tried creating a event listener but this   only works on the main screen. When I transition to the barcode scanner my event listener   seems to no longer apply.

Anyways my question is does anyone know a way to disable the menu button while using the   phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner?

Thanks